# How do I pass a value rom my REST endpoint to my PostgreSQL time_bucket_gapfill() function

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, function, timescaledb

I'm trying to call the time_bucket_gapfill() function from my PostgreSQL database with TimescaleDB via a REST endpoint. Obviously, I use the function to aggregate my data in buckets of a chosen interval. If the user requests one week of data I aggregate the data on daily basis, if they request one day's data I aggregate the data on an hourly basis, etc.

I'm using the time_bucket_gapfill() function like this:

```
time_bucket_gapfill('1 day', timestamp) <- This gives me data on daily basis
time_bucket_gapfill('1 hour', timestamp) <- This gives me data on hourly basis
```

However, the first parameter in the function is not hardcoded in the query, it's fed to the query by the REST endpoint and fed as a Data type String. This is what causes the problem because it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: function public.time_bucket_gapfill(character varying, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

How do I inject the value in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the signature of the available function using `\df` command:

```sql
 \df public.time_bucket_gapfill;
List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | bigint
Argument data types | bucket_width bigint, ts bigint, start bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint, finish bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint
Type                | func
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | integer
Argument data types | bucket_width integer, ts integer, start integer DEFAULT NULL::integer, finish integer DEFAULT NULL::integer
Type                | func
-[ RECORD 3 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | date
Argument data types | bucket_width interval, ts date, start date DEFAULT NULL::date, finish date DEFAULT NULL::date
Type                | func
-[ RECORD 4 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | timestamp with time zone
Argument data types | bucket_width interval, ts timestamp with time zone, start timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp with time zone, finish timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp with time zone
Type                | func
-[ RECORD 5 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | timestamp without time zone
Argument data types | bucket_width interval, ts timestamp without time zone, start timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone, finish timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone
Type                | func
-[ RECORD 6 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | time_bucket_gapfill
Result data type    | smallint
Argument data types | bucket_width smallint, ts smallint, start smallint DEFAULT NULL::smallint, finish smallint DEFAULT NULL::smallint
Type                | func
```

As you can see you have `character varying` and you need to convert it to an interval.

```sql
select '1 month'::interval;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
interval | 1 mon
```

Comment: I've already tried that. The problem with that is that JPA does not understand it it says: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"..

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Would you mind adding the full stack trace exception?

Answer (score 0):

If your JPA is not allowing you to proceed on this way, you can write another SQL function that wraps this one over fixing the types of the parameters:

```sql
create function public.time_bucket_gapfill(character varying, timestamp without time zone) returns timestamp without time zone as $$
select time_bucket_gapfill($1::interval, $2);
$$ language sql immutable;
```

testing:

```sql
select time_bucket_gapfill('1 day'::varchar, now()::timestamp);
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+--------------------
time_bucket_gapfill | 2021-06-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: I think I fixed it by using time_bucket_gapfill(cast(? as interval), timestamp).. It looks like it works, but I don't know much about cast. I wonder how much it affects the performance in case of many records...

Comment: I'd recommend just using the cast function as above as otherwise you may end up doing the cast on every row (rather than just once) which can add significant overhead.

Comment: The cast here should run just once because it's being run on a constant input, whereas the function has one constant input and one varying on every row.